# could not load an object because it is not available on this machine - Autocad 2016

Tags: autocad

I have a .dvb file that works with autocad 2010, and I just downloaded and installed autocad 2016's trial version. I tried loading the .dvb file using VBAIDE and running it, and this error shows.

[image]

Which autocad version is best suited for a company?

Edit 1:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the problem is because of a missing component of Windows Forms and not because of something in AutoCad.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov what do you forms? I am loading the plugin to new machine. could you elaborate more pls

Comment: You have to search for "windows forms could not load an object" in google. You will find out that the problem is because of Windows Forms framework and not because of AutoCAD. One such example [here](http://bit.ly/1TKRlvp) and another one [here](http://bit.ly/1J6FIJz) and a third one [here](http://bit.ly/1O4Glec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After open your project on VBAIDE, go to menu Tools>References. The list include all the references used on the project, included the missing ones. You should install the missing references.

From the error message, the Microsoft Forms it one of the missing references.

Comment: microsoft forms 2.0 object library is checked

Comment: pls add a print screen of your project reference window

Comment: thanks for the screen shot, I can see that some references are for AutoCAD 2016, other for AutoCAD 2010. You need to adjust it to use the same version. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the VBA Enabler?
It is a separate install from AutoCAD.
It can be found here. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/downloads/caas/downloads/content/download-the-microsoft-visual-basic-for-applications-module-vba.html